# How to get calculated value from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, reference

I have c++ and c# codes.
When I run my code, I want c++ codes calculate a value and my c# take the value and use it.

The value will change in c++, while running. And c# will take it.

c++ codes (simple):

```
int main() 
{
    int x;
    void (int a); //calculate x and return x 
}
```

how can I do this?
I tried with dll or I tried within adding reference. didn't work.

what should write in c# for getting x value?

edit: I'm trying to do like this:

NativeLib.h:

```
#ifndef _NATIVELIB_H_

#define _NATIVELIB_H_

#ifndef MYAPI
  #define MYAPI 
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

//MYAPI void print_line(const char* str);
MYAPI void print_line(const int a);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // _NATIVELIB_H_
```

NativeLib.cpp:

```
#include "NativeLib.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 10;

MYAPI void print_line(const int a) {
    int a = x;
}
```

c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PInvokeTest {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      print_line(a);
    }

    [DllImport("NativeLib.dll")]
    private static extern void print_line(int a);
  }
}
```

why do I get error?

Comment: Create a DLL of your C++ code with exported C style functions (no name-mangling) and then use [P/Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/consuming-unmanaged-dll-functions) in C# to call them.

Comment: @ckuri can you give me some example? because I'm new learner of c# and c++. also thanks for answering, sir.

Comment: See https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/403285/P-Invoke-Tutorial-Basics-Part for an example.

Comment: @ckuri I did, but I get error. I added the codes with editting.

Comment: @ckuri also what about JSON? a person said me there is a JSON communicate between c++ and c#

Comment: You would use JSON when you make both of them communicate per network (TCP, HTTP).

Comment: ı just want to give a value from c++ to c# while running (the value will change while running)

Comment: Also I am thinking to create txt in c++ and read in c#. is it the worst way?

Comment: @ckuri can you take the responsibility and give me some examples too please?

Comment: It should be `MYAPI void print_line(int a)` in C++ because `const int*` means a pointer to an int, whereas in C# you just specified `int a` directly. Please append your post with the exact error message you get and where you get it.

Comment: @ckuri all codes are in here in the first comment. please take a look and help me, mister